# Getting WebDriver working with Firefox

Tags: selenium, webdriver, codeception

Using Laravel 5+ with Vagrant.

I have selenium running using:

```
java -jar vendor/se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/usr/bin/firefox"
```

using a headless display:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
```

However when i run codeception:

```
 ./vendor/bin/codecept run selenium --steps
```

I get the following error:

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

I am confused with server and ports that i should be using.
Currently i access site through `http://localhost:8000`
however that is outside vagrant.

I observe `$url = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`, inside `api\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php`

As the error outputs :

> 127.0.0.1 on port 7055.

Comment: I am ultimately trying to get acceptance test working so i can test my angular elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switched to chrome web driver, was less complicated, more compatible and works fine for me.

1. Download chrome webdriver or composer require
2. Setup environment

   nohup sudo Xvfb :10 -ac &

   export DISPLAY=:10

   java -jar vendor/se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin="/usr/bin/google-chrome" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="vendor/bin/chromedriver"

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?? "Use chrome" is absolutely not a valid answer for "Getting WebDriver working with Firefox"

Comment: "Why is this the accepted answer??" is not an answer, when you find a better solution, post it.

Comment: your answer is a possible workaround for some people, but is by no means an answer to the question asked.  If someone needs to get Firefox working, how is an explanation of how to use Chrome addressing the question whatsoever?  People posting unrelated workarounds shouldn't be rewarded.  Just because you solved your own problem using something unrelated to what you asked, doesn't make it a correct answer.  This is a Q&A site afterall.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should download latest [geckodriver from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set property `Dwebdriver.gecko.driver` with  downloaded geckodriver path from your system when you run the `selenium-server-standalone.jar` as below :

```
java -jar vendor/se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/usr/bin/firefox" -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver = "path/to/downloaded geckodriver
```

**Note** : Just like the other drivers available to `Selenium` from other browser vendors, `Mozilla` has released an executable `geckodriver` that will run alongside with the latest firefox browser. For more information you should [follow this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver).

Now you need to set capability with `marionette` to `true` during initialisation of `RemoteWebDriver` inside `api\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php` as :

```
$capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);
```

Full example code :

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
```

Comment: why should i use gecko driver?

Comment: what line should this be at? $capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);

Comment: Because for the latest firefox browser Mozilla has released an executable geckodriver and without this executable you can't run with the latest browser..:)

Comment: If you don't want with geckodriver you need to downgrade you firefox version...:)

Comment: This capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);  line tells to webdriver to find geckodriver executable to run firefox browser..:)

Comment: Have look this link for more details..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver..